# Image not loading in my html page when using Live Server extension in VS Code

Tags: html

I have started studying web development and decided to use VS Code. It is currently running on a Linux Mint dist (19.03). Decided to add some extensions, including Live Server so I don't need to constantly hit F5 to see the changes. Problem is: I inserted an image on my html page and if I open the page through Live Server, the picture just doesn't show up, but if I go to the HTML file and open it, it shows perfectly. Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you! I am leaving the code here so you can have a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>DOM</title>
  </head>
  <script src="dom.js"></script>
  <body>
    <img src="/../HTML/me.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

/../ in the img src tag does not look correct.

Comment: even if I delete the "/" the problem remains the same